# function "this" set some type context + original "this" context

Tags: typescript

How do I merge given context of "this" with original "this" context I have in a function. Example:

```
interface Repository {
    find(): void
    findOne(): void
}

interface CustomRepository {
    [key: string]: (this: Repository & this) => any // note: I tried to add & this but it doesn't work.
}

const repository: CustomRepository = {
    findNew() {
        this.findOne()
    },
    findOld() {
        // here I would like to access find(), findOne(), findNew() using this.
        // this.
    }
}
```

If there is issue / feature request / discussion in TypeScript repository, link is appreciated.

Comment: Your example works so far. `this` is of type `Repository & CustomRepository` in `repository`, so you can access explicit props `find`, `findOne` (intelli sense), but you can also invoke arbitrary methods `this.findWhatever()` due to the index signature in `CustomRepository`.

Comment: Maybe I am not getting it yet but you can get all those methods if you used classes. Let me know if this helps or doesn't so I can change my answer.

Comment: @ford04 nope, it does not. I can't access findNew in findOld, see http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEoQA4HsDOwxZQCeyA3gLABQyNyMoAJgBQCUAXMgG5bANW11GAeRARWHbryoBfKlVCRYiFAGEArjgIBbdNjwFiZfrQDaAawhEOmqKADmAXQ6tkAXgB8yOCBIB6X8ggWJAcAJLIYLYQDBFYXgwxAGQRABbAOMgARmpgyPjIDFgQOCAA5LkA7oRmAHQycpQIWCCayFCYuPiEVsjqmlg6HfrdbkbUtPQgDAByEBVMYGk4HLqdBkQsYwIC-qnpNZPMLMY00gA0J4JTQgA2R1vbNLsp0CjhVWp3yDfAFrFeCCQOAyh1YZyuDBEYhY4MOs3mmw09j2ODq40eu0W+0uskouKAA

Comment: @pleerock yeah, as said this is simply because of the index signature permitting all kinds of properties/methods, like [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcDOYD2BbAJQgAcdNhcoBPZAbwFgAoZF5AbQGsIqAuZbKKADmAXT4AKAJTIAvAD5kcEFSatkMUABMAysQgJgcADZS+ANxzBNyAPQ3kmiBpAo8EMAAscmzMio50ZBcIawgAD2IjYANIIxVGAF8mJkcEIzgoFAQcEGxkTNI+DGx8IlJySni7IJxkUFiozAhclHs4dFxkbLxI9xQPaBQAI312puQcGDqQRzD+YCEQODB0TKYCnAA6MChjPfWSHDYAIhh0M+ORZMYNzecdPQNjKWugA). You would have to declare extra properties, to have "explicit" access to them.

Comment: @ford04 yeah I know I can define methods explicitely, but I expect non-explicitely defined methods to work. I can't define methods explicitely because my interface is generic